# Serve only requested content range

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, video, header

Using Node.js, I'm trying to create a video server which serves only a small part of a larger media file.

Following this [gist](https://gist.github.com/paolorossi/1993068) I've been able to create a video server and feed that to a html5 video player using:

```
<video controls width="500">
   <source src="http://127.0.0.1:1337/" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

However, the range request starts at 0 and potentially buffers beyond a point of interest (if say I only wanted to view under 25 seconds of video).

Ideally I'd the ability to playback from some arbitrary point for a known duration and serve only that content. I know one solution is to seek to a specific point in the video client side and stop playback after a known duration; but is it possible to serve JUST the video content required?

Is the only fool proof way of achieving this to use a tool like FFMpeg to trim a larger clip into smaller chunks?

Thanks in advance,

GW

Answer (score 1):

Digging deeper into the w3c specifications, I found [Media Frags](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/).

```
    <video id="video1" controls width="270">
        <source src="http://127.0.0.1:1337/#t=9.000001,11" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
```

It seems strange that I found this difficult to find, but it solves my problem.